# How to constrain a generic using AnyZodObject without losing information

Tags: typescript, zod

I have the function below which is intended to update an existing zod schema

```
export const meta = <T extends z.AnyZodObject>(definedFields: T) => definedFields.catchall(z.unknown())
```

However the resulting type has information stripped from it, which I believe is happening because `T extends z.AnyZodObject` constrains the object resulting in information being lost.

See the example below ([typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcBEyEAJvgLABQlApgB6SxwDGEAdgM7wjUwCGcAXjgAeACpw6Maq2LsUAOgCCrAJ4AtEgHkARgCtqTGAD4AFMWqZgrasQBiwagBtZALjiiAlIKNxzl63YOzuzyTLwwTAAWvI6OJsjyAK6sANasEADurCYeHpSULBxcKgDKUdQg-EIJEHoGMCZInFBWAOb2TsRuCc1tOeh5VBQA9MNw7OWVtjggALI8-LwycFC8GWWRFfzskRCJznBWcDCb0Cor1Oz78Ecn1OO83OOT-CbaifB358RsAOQwg0KnGemymM3mfEEcG4fBMIFKL0BbGBq3WLyh8I2W1C4SiMTiCWSaUy2Vy+QoMBUYHuEN4WMqUISVkw1Cgwkp1IgmBBW2muFpRkoHPuACU1vSqgpmaz2VTqFyVuKXoKhkD4AA3ACMblpEqhTRgLVY7SCXQIvHw6AKyI1ACY3GK0aDJQajSbOm58BarUMtfJesaOgdRnAAOo4Y1uAASvDkwrgSxUlHVtv9hraQeIcBDAGFoFB6tHY8c5eN08bKEA)).

```
import { z } from "zod"

export const meta = <T extends z.AnyZodObject>(definedFields: T) => definedFields.catchall(z.unknown())

const mySchema = z.object({ stringField: z.string() })

// schemaFromMeta and rawSchema should in theory result in the same schema (but they don't)
const schemaFromMeta = meta(mySchema)
const rawSchema = mySchema.catchall(z.unknown())

type MetaSchema = z.infer<typeof schemaFromMeta>
type RawSchema = z.infer<typeof rawSchema>

const v1: MetaSchema = { stringField: "a" }
const v2: RawSchema = { stringField: "a" }

v1.stringField // Wrong: Has type any
v2.stringField // Correct: Has type string
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to workaround this?

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.